# Setting value on product which is adde to cart?

Tags: magento2, quoteitem

Magento 2.4.6

Is there a way to set a value on the item which is added to the cart which can be accessed anywhere else, like in templates for example?

I am listening to the `checkout_cart_product_add_after` event and am trying to set it like this in my observer:

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
    
    $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');
    $item = ($item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item);
    $item->setIsSample(true); // thats were I set the value
    $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
}
```

The code is reached, but the setter seems to have no effect, calling getIsSample() returns nothing in a template ... is this the wrong way? I also tried with `setData('issample', true)`, doesnt work either.

Thanks!